# How to call non generic method from a generic one

Tags: java, generics

How to call non generic method from a generic one:

```
    class Test {
        ...
        public <T> int someFunction1(T someParam) {
            return someFunction2(someParam);
        }

        public int someFunction2(String someParam) {
           return 1;
        }

        public int someFunction2(Integer someParam) {
        return 1;
        }
    }

 Test t = new Test;
t.someFunction1(new String("1"));
t.someFunction1(new Integer(5));
```

Also is it possible to do this at compile time, rather than at runtime?

Comment: Please provide more information about what is not working : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As said in my answer, you can somehow do that, but it sounds like "bad design". So question back to you: what kind of problem do you intend to solve this way?

Comment: [GhostCa](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1531124/ghostcat)
So this type of practice doesn't consider bad in C++ right? I just wanted to know is it possible to do the same in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler can not determine that `someParam` in `someFunction1` is either a `String` or an `Integer`. Something like this will work:

```
public <T extends String> int someFunction1(T someParam) {
    return someFunction2(someParam);
}

public int someFunction2(String someParam) {
    return 1;
}
```

If you wanted it to be `String`/`Integer` you would need to create some datatype or created overloaded definition of `someFunction1` where `T` is bound to `Integer`

Or just some "ugly" casts:

```
public <T> int someFunction1(T someParam) {
    if (someParam instanceof Integer)
        return someFunction2((Integer) someParam);
    else if (someParam instanceof String)
        return someFunction2((String) someParam);
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected String or Integer")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the argument type and according to its type to explicitly cast and call correct method:

```
public <T> int someFunction1(T someParam) {
    if (someParam instanceof Integer)
        return someFunction2((Integer)someParam);
    else if (someParam instanceof String)
        return someFunction2((String)someParam);
    else
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unexepected type: "+someParam.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same in compile time?

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan : You mean resolving the type? Note, that's not possible as the method cannot know from which context it's going to be called. The above is the only way.

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan how are you invoking `someFunction1`? Do you have references to `Integer`, `String` etc, or do you just have an `Object`? If it is the former, you can simply rename all of the `someFunction2` overloads to `someFunction1`; the `someFunction1(String)` overload will be picked over `someFunction1(T)`, since it is more specific after erasure. If not, you're stuck with the `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 0):

The generics don't add anything. You can (and should) remove the type variable from the method without changing behaviour:

```
public int someFunction1(Object someParam) {
```

and then apply one of the `if/else` `instanceof` chains proposed in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This answer would only work if the the parameter is always a string or a Integer

```
public <T> int someFunction1(T someParam) {
    try {
        return someFunction2((String) someParam);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        try {
            return someFunction2((int) someParam);
        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And for the record: it is a really bad way to "solve" the problem. In contrast to other languages, you do **not** use exceptions like this in java.